# not able to embed python tensorflow code in c++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, python-c-api

I am building NIST FRVT11 library. I have core code in python, that I want to call from c++, I have followed offical Python C API docs to use python functions in c++.

I am able to load and predict with keras model once during initialization stage. But cannot predict from the same model after that `model.predict` function takes inifite time.
I'm not even able to load the model, this time `tf.keras.models.load_model` takes inifite time.

I am not getting any error that I can paste here :(

NIST wants everything to be packaged within library, so I have built python locally and attaching that in the submission.

python: 3.9.13
tensorflow: 2.8.0
keras: 2.8.0

python code

```
import tensorflow as tf
def get_model(model_path):
    embedding_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
    return embedding_model 

def predict(model, img):
    out= model.predict(img)
    return out
```

c++ code

```
int call_python_code(const std::string &configDir)
{
    this->configDir = configDir;
    // add directory to sys path
    std::string command_sys_path_to_append = "import sys, os\n"
                "sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '" + this- 
               >configDir + "'))\n";
    PyRun_SimpleString(command_sys_path_to_append.c_str());

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *p_module_name = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("fr"); // fr.py file
    this->p_module = PyImport_Import(p_module_name);

    // load the model from c++
    PyObject *outer_tuple_2 = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(outer_tuple_2, 0, PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(this->configDir.c_str()));
    PyObject *p_fucntion_model = PyObject_GetAttrString(p_module, "get_model");
this->p_embedding_model_object = PyObject_CallObject(p_fucntion_model, outer_tuple_2);

 

 // get prediction 

    PyObject *p_function_predict= PyObject_GetAttrString(p_module, "predict");


PyObject *full_args = PyTuple_New(2); 
PyTuple_SetItem(full_args, 0, this->p_fucntion_model);
PyTuple_SetItem(full_args, 1, <image array>);
PyObject *outer_tuple = PyTuple_New(1);
PyTuple_SetItem(outer_tuple, 0, full_args);
PyObject *p_return_tuple = PyObject_CallObject(p_function_predict, outer_tuple);

}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you're doing, but: many Python modules (including Numpy) can't handle being loaded multiple times. For this reason you should call `Py_Initialize` _only once_. I suspect you many be calling it many times.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks David for the comment :)
I tried both ways i.e. by using `Py_Initialize` and `PyImport_Import` in separate function that is called once during initialization phase. I am able to use `cv2.dnn` model multiple times. I don't what's the reason with tensorflow.

I'm trying to build this(https://github.com/usnistgov/frvt/tree/master/11). According to NIST, final deliverable should be implementation in c++

I have full working code in python with me, I want to call that code from c++